# Plot Time Date Chart On Excel

Tags: excel, charts, timeserieschart

I have an excel sheet with the following columns

Date      Time      Value

I want to plot a chart with Time on X-Axis, Value on Y-Axis and Date as a line on the chart.
How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want the Date parallel to x or y axis? Can you give an example of the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do:

I refer to this data for example [image]

1. Select the (time,value) pairs for the 16th, insert a scatter plot. You will then get this [image]
2. now right click on the chart, choose `Select data` and `Add`. Select the pairs for the 17th on the appropriate X and Y field. Edit also the label.
   You will now get this [image]
3. Repeat step 2 for the 18th, you'll get this [image]

Comment: I am actually analyzing stock market data. I want to know at what time the prices are volatile. So on X-Axis there would be Time. On Y-Axis there would be value and on the chart there would be different lines. Each line would represent a date

Comment: so you want, let's say, a line to be 15th Oct, another line to be 16th and so on?